# CSS селектор для всех DIV потомков элемента кроме первого

Tags: javascript, css

Как построить выражение?

`querySelectorAll(':not(div:nth-child(1)')` выдает ошибку - "Не валидный селектор".

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div>Hello world #1</div>
<div>Hello world #2</div>
<div>Hello world #3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

*P.S. Вот на Codepen, если так удобнее: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/OrZJzv)*

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо так

```
:not(:first-of-type)
```

Comment: Извините, а как сделать именно для элементов div? Не получается сделать так, чтобы консоль не ругалась, спасибо.